# Automatically downloading all pdf documents given a list of keywords

Tags: python, pdf, indexing, download

Is there any way to create a python script that will search all of the PDFs online given a few keywords and automatically download them? For example, If I want to download all the PDFs online pertaining to "raspberry pi heat sensor".

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do such a thing. Grab a keyboard and write the code. Is that an acceptable answer to your question? If not, then your question is far too broad in scope and you should [edit] to make it more specific. See [ask].

Comment: It's not like there's a list of "all the PDFs online".

Comment: @BrenBarn God may have left one in the Bible...

Comment: @Julien: No. That one was carved in stone for archiving, stashed behind a burning bush for safekeeping and then deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the google apis

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/

They offer access to many google functionalities (like search).
Since google allows you to specify a file-type, I'm sure the same can be done using their APIs.